# concatenation of variables with probability of null or 0

Tags: java, eclipse

Ok i don't know how to exactly explain completely what my issue is i'm facing to get what i want, but the basis of what i'm trying to accomplish here is...i don't want a ***-> ; <-*** to show up if the variable is **Null** or **0**. Something I've attempted so far is a scanner input where when you run the code it asks to input values that are > 0 and if you input one thats not it'll give an invalid input error. Im trying to find a different method where its not needed to keep repeating this method for 20 or more. Like i said im just trying to have it input the numbers automatically, and if theres no number in one of the variables it would skip it and not put another " ; " and just put the ones that do have numbers with the semicolon. So what i'm looking at to accomplish is listed in the image bellow :

[image: what im trying to accomplish exactly]

Comment: Hmm ..sure we can help. But what you tried so far ? and why is that picture there in first place ?

Comment: i've tried creating a scanner input method where in the end you type out the numbers manually and it will display all numbers typed up that are greater than 0 but im trying to find another method to come up with whats needed instead of having to type everything in every time then finding out whats either Null or 0

Comment: The picture is there just as a reference to see what it is im looking to accomplish incase i wasn't making sense in my description.

Comment: Please edit your question and add any helpful information for users to know.

Comment: Can you put  individual string to an array??

Comment: Ok i edited it more hopefully its more helpful

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulties to understand your question. I am also not an english speaking person....

If I understood you want this:

```
String a,b,c,d,e, all;
all = "";
if(a!=null && a!=0){
    all += a;
}
if(b!=null && b!=0){
    all += b;
}
if(c!=null && c!=0){
    all += c;
}
...
if(all != ""){
    //something
} else {
    // something else
}
```

Note that I am not permutating, I am sequencially checking for values in each variable then performing the desired effect.... I just concatenated strings, if you want to add stuffs like (space),`;` (semicolon), its up to you.